# Is there a simpler way to switch a symbor for an image than usign switch-cases?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and for a project I tried to develop a classic PacMan game with JavaScript. It works but my code just gets too long, especially while creating the map. This makes it a lot more difficult to create different levels.

The way it worked for me, was using and ‘switch – case’. But I have to change it manually every time. I was wondering, it its possible to simplify the code.
I tried creating an ‘for-loop’ and working with ‘if-statements’ but I could not bring it to work. Do you have any Tipps?

This is the start of the code, it goes on for another 200+ lines...

```
function createImage(src) {
    const image = new Image()
    image.src = src
    return image}

map.forEach((row, zeilen) => {
    row.forEach((symbol, spalten) => {
        switch(symbol) {

            case 'a':
                boundaries.push(
                    new Boundary({ 
                        position: {
                            x: Boundary.width * spalten
                            y: Boundary.height * zeilen
                        },
                        image: createImage('../javascript/images/board/boundaryHorizontal.png')
                    }))
                break
            
            case 'b':
                boundaries.push(
                    new Boundary({
                        position: {
                            x: Boundary.width * spalten,
                            y: Boundary.height * zeilen 
                        },
                        image: createImage('../javascript/images/board/boundaryVertikal.png')
                    }))
                break
```

Comment: This may be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: For future reference, add 4 spaces in front of each line of your code to make it a code block. This can be done automatically by clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: You may also want to look at the open source [Phaser](https://phaser.io/) game framework which can do much of this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I solved it this way:

```
map.forEach((row, i) => { 
    row.forEach((symbol, j) =>{ 
        const position = {
            x: Boundary.width * j,
            y: Boundary.height * i
        };
        const positionPP = {
            x: Boundary.width * j + Boundary.width /2,
            y: Boundary.height * i + Boundary.height /2
        };
        const imgPaths = {
            'a': './Images/Spielfeld/boundaryHorizontal.png',
            ...
        };
        if (symbol === ' ') { 
        } else if (symbol === '.') {
            pellets.push( new Pellet({ position: positionPP}));
        } else if (symbol === 'p') {
            powerUps.push( new PowerUp({ position: positionPP}));
        } else {
            boundaries.push( new Boundary({ position , image: createImage(imgPaths[symbol])}));
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as an answer to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the value instead of using switch/case.

```
const images = new Map([
  ['a', '../image for a'],
  ['b', '../image for b'],
  ['c', '../image for c'],
]);

boundaries.push(
    new Boundary({ 
        position: {
            x: Boundary.width * spalten
            y: Boundary.height * zeilen
        },
        image: createImage(images.get(symbol))
    }))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this input. It helped a lot :)